# Spring 4.1's JsonView and Hibernate4Module

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a project which liberally uses lazy loading via the org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter view filter.

If I disable this, I have to add a new message converter in my rest servlet configuration:

```
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    return messageConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    // Add the custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
    converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());

    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

However, doing so seems to break the behavior of @JsonView: the existence of the @JsonView annotation no longer seems to filter in/out any properties.

My guess is Hibernate4Module doesn't support @JsonView, but if that's the case, how can I use Spring 4.1's @JsonView support and make Jackson cognizant of lazy-loaded Hibernate entities? The only solution so far seems to be avoiding Hibernate4Module and relying on the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter filter.

Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using spring 4.1.*, make sure you are changing

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.*;
```

to

```
import org.fasterxml.jackson.annotate.*;
```

in your case its

> import org.fasterxml.jackson.annotate.JsonView;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure the DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION feature to be false. By default all properties without explicit view definition are included in serialization. Out of box Spring will disable this default for you. So if you want to use your own custom mapper you will probably want to disable it or all the properties with out @JsonView annotations will get added to you JSON.

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
```